# Change the style of a label with ASP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I get an error, "myfunction is not a member of ASP.inicio_aspx". To make to work i must create the button with code HTML, not with code ASP, but using an asp button doesnt work. I want enable and disable a label with a button.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var estado = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientId %>');
            estado.style.visibility = "visible"; // use hidden if you want to hide it again.
        }
    </script>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="55pt" Visible="true" style="visibility:hidden;"></asp:Label>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Prova</button>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" onclick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="true" />
```

Comment: You should use `OnClientClick`: `<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClientClick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="true" />`.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, It works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Button.OnClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick?view=netframework-4.7.2) property used to call server-side event associated with [`Click`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.7.2) event handler. To call client-side JS function from server control markup, you should use [`Button.OnClientClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Button_OnClientClick) property, as in example below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClientClick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="true" />
```